# throw an error with a statusCode inside NextJs to test the customized error page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

So I have built a custom error page, to allow internationalization. This is working fine. The only way for me to test it though is to enter gibberish as route. For example: `localhost:<port>/gibberish`

so it will redirect me to the custom error page.
I have been trying to create a page named `errortest` and inside that page, I want to throw an error with a given statusCode, so NextJs catches it and redirects to the custom error page.

Thing is, I have no idea how to do that.

Something along this:

```
const ErrorTest = () => {
  //Throw Error
};

export default ErrorTest;
```

Comment: Have you read my post? This is exactly what I did. I want to create a page which throws an error, to get redirected to that page.
So my question is about how to throw an error inside a NextJS component, or more general, how to throw an error with NextJs/Express/React.

Comment: `return { statusCode: 404 }`

Comment: ??
Like this:
```const ErrorTest = () => {
  return { statusCode: 302 };
};

export default ErrorTest;
```
That doesn't work. Sorry I am having trouble throwing an error from inside a component, is it clear what I want?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well, and I think the easiest way is to import the `_error.js` page into another test page and render it with the status code of your choice. You can find this in the Next.js docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#reusing-the-built-in-error-page). The code example you'll find looks like this:

```js
import Error from 'next/error'

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/next.js')
  const errorCode = res.ok ? false : res.statusCode
  const json = await res.json()

  return {
    props: { errorCode, stars: json.stargazers_count },
  }
}

// Note the page returns your custom error page
export default function Page({ errorCode, stars }) {
  if (errorCode) {
    return <Error statusCode={errorCode} />
  }

  return <div>Next stars: {stars}</div>
}
```

You can import your custom error page into another page and make modifications there without having to run `yarn build` and `yarn start`. This is particularly useful if you want to update the styles or fix any issues which might come up during development (e.g. localization).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an exception in your component, e.g. null pointer. Though throwing an err should do as well.

Then you need to

`yarn build && yarn start`

When running the build you will see next.js showing your custom err page.